# h2o water meter on windows - "[Not linux" message

Tags: windows-8.1, h2o

Water meter (CPU meter) does not work on my Windows standalone h2o instance. It shows "not linux" message.

Using version h2o-3.10.4.6 of h2o on Windows 8.1.

[image]

Was the feature not yet implemented for Windows deployments or is there another thing i need to consider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Water Meter is only implemented for Linux systems (by reading `/proc/stat` data), it won't work on neither Windows nor MacOS. From what I recall we don't have anyone working on a Windows/Mac version so if you're feel like it then you can contribute, you can check the [source code here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/blob/master/src/main/java/water/api/WaterMeterPerfbar.java) and the Linux implementation [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/water/util/LinuxProcFileReader.java). The tricky part is that it has to use open libraries (due to licensing).

Comment: would python be an option? something like this (found on stackoverflow as well): 
from __future__ import print_function
import psutil
print(psutil.cpu_percent())
print(psutil.virtual_memory()) #  physical memory usage

Comment: No, it would have to be part of out core platform which is written in Java

Comment: The major reason this was never done for any platform but Linux is H2O has always shipped as pure Java (for simplicity of distribution), and getting these numbers (kernel CPU tick info) out for any platform besides Linux requires C code.  A second minor reason is most people that run H2O distributed (in a cloud or a Hadoop environment, for example) use Linux, and remote distributed environments really benefit from having the built-in Water Meter.  If you can run top or htop locally, the need is less acute.  This may be worth revisiting in the future as other C/C++ components are added to H2O.